# Postgres - How do I call a stored plpgsql function, have I made a mistake in the function itself?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I Have written a Postgres function, using plpgsql, but get a 'syntax error, unexpected character' when I call it using:

```
PERFORM create_user('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Here is the Postgres function definition, copied from pgAdmin:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(_username character varying, _passwordhash character varying, _email character varying)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO users(id, username, passwordhash, email) VALUES (DEFAULT, _username, _passwordhash, _email) RETURNING id;


END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION create_user(character varying, character varying, character varying)
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Can anyone identify what I have done wrong here?

Also, I am trying to access it in node.js through 'pg', but I have not been able to call the function without a syntax error from pgAdmin anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you try your function like below; by declaring a `INT` variable and then capture the generated `id` sequence into the variable. Finally return that variable.

In some Postgres forum post I had found that the construct `RETURNING id` is not supported in all versions. so, you may like to circumvent it other way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(_username character varying,
                                       _passwordhash character varying, 
                                       _email character varying)
RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE retvar integer; <-- declare the variable
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO users(id, username, passwordhash, email) 
  VALUES (DEFAULT, _username, _passwordhash, _email) RETURNING id into retvar;
                                                             <-- get return id
return retvar; <-- return the variable
END;
$BODY$
```

Comment: I've managed to get it to work using the following:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_user(username character varying, password_hash character varying, email character varying)`
`RETURNS integer AS`
    `$BODY$INSERT INTO users (username, passwordhash, email)`
    `VALUES ($1, $2, $2)`
    `RETURNING id$BODY$`
      `LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE`
      `COST 100;`
    `ALTER FUNCTION create_user(character varying, character varying, character varying)`
      `OWNER TO postgres;`

I think like your example, it uses the SQL language, rather than plpgsql.

Comment: It's not actually a stored plpgsql function as far as I can tell.

Comment: @user1315172, Good to know that you got it worked. with your comment do you mean my answer didn't helped you?

Comment: Your comment was helpful, but I have not run it to see if it's the correct answer to the question and that it works. The way I solved the problem was not using the method that I framed this question as, it was using normal SQL, not plpgsql. I'm also interested in knowing if your example is written in plpgsql or in standard (ANSI?) SQL. By the looks of things it uses plpgsql because the parameters are not written as $1, $2 etc. Would writing 'LANGUAGE plpgsql' in your example change what it does at all?

Comment: Do you mean your example is written in plpgsql?

Comment: Yes it is since your posted code is written in plpgsql. Moreover, I haven't added anything special. just went by your posted code and modified the body a bit.

Comment: Because I had not solved it in a different way (with normal SQL) when I posted the question. Anyway, thanks for fixing my code. Once I've verified it works I'll confirm the question as answered.

Comment: It took an extra `LANGUAGE plpgsql` statement after `$BODY$`, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're typing this in pgAdmin's SQL editor:

```
PERFORM create_user('a', 'b', 'c');
```

This fails with a syntax error because `PERFORM` is not a regular SQL instruction. Looking at the reference list of [SQL commands](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) in the documentation, you'll see that it's not part of them.

`PERFORM` belongs to the pl/pgsql language only and as such, may only be used only from inside a pl/pgsql function. It's [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html) as:

> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but
>   discard the result, for example when calling a function that has
>   side-effects but no useful result value. To do this **in PL/pgSQL**,
>   use the PERFORM statement:
>
> PERFORM query;
>
> This executes query and discards the result

To call a function from pgAdmin or from another client application, just use `SELECT`, no matter what the language of the function, and no matter what type it returns.